# Macbook Display Screen Coating

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

I've noticed a **black** color coat on my Macbook screen.
 It's a very  thin layer coating and whenever I tried to
 clean the display,  I got some carbon black dust sticking
 to the cleaning cloth.

I would like to know whether I can
 re-coat my screen since the layer has been deteriorating ever since.

PS: MacbookPro is 15inch 2013 late December model.

Comment: Related: [Apple Launches Quality Program for MacBook Pro Anti-Reflective Coating Issues](https://www.macrumors.com/2015/10/17/apple-mbp-ar-coating-quality-program-staingate/).

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue for Retina MacBooks and Apple is aware of this.
You can search for 'staingate' for more info.
There is a replacement program going on, you can read about that at [MacRumors website](http://www.macrumors.com/2015/10/17/apple-mbp-ar-coating-quality-program-staingate/).
You'll have to make an appointment at a genius bar where they will check if it is still covered.

> Apple will replace Retina displays on affected MacBook or MacBook Pro models for free within three years from the date of original purchase, or one year from October 16, 2015, whichever is longer. Affected customers that have already incurred out-of-warranty costs may be eligible for a refund through AppleCare support.
>
> Affected customers can book an appointment with a Genius Bar or visit an Apple Authorized Service Provider to determine if their MacBook is eligible for coverage. Apple does not currently plan on announcing the Quality Program publicly on its support website, according to sources, but may contact some customers directly.

Comment: i did notice staingate . The replacement program was only for Macbook Pro's brought after 2015.

Comment: No it is not, I quote: Apple will replace Retina displays on affected MacBook or MacBook Pro models for free within three years from the date of original purchase, or one year from October 16, 2015, whichever is longer.

Comment: This does mean that the warranty is expired but for loyal customers apple is known to make an exception

Comment: I don't see myself lucky enough for replacement program . I was thinking if there is any way I can replenish the coating layer.

Comment: You can always try, perhaps go to an authorised service provider instead, those are usually more forgiving